# SQL Server : how to decrease database size after bulk delete tables and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a 100 GB database after deleting multiple records. I want to decrease the database size.

After shrinking the database, I am able to

I will 1gb from 100 GB but In many blog suggested do not use shrink database operation. It will create fragmentation and performance issue.

So are there any alternative way to decrease database size after bulk delete operation?

After bulk delete I have tried database->task->shrink->database

It is decreasing the database size from 100 GB to 1 GB, but many blogs suggest avoiding to shrink database - so what is alternative way to reduce database size after bulk delete?

Answer (score 3):

> In many blog suggested do not use shrink database operation

Don't believe everything you read.  If you delete a large number of rows, and have *permanently* reduced the amount of data stored in the database, then shrink it.  You just don't want to shrink if the database is going to grow right back to its original size.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Only one confusion …..will shrink operation affect to  query execution time ?

Comment: It should not have a significant impact on query execution time.